# Inserting NA's into specific rows and columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, insert, na

Here is a sample of my dataframe:

```
df3 <- data.frame(Frame = c(219388, 219389, 219390, 211387, 211388, 211389), Time = c("2020-06-05 13:26:39", "2020-06-05 13:26:39", "2020-06-05 13:26:39", "2020-06-05 13:26:39", "2020-06-05 13:26:39", "2020-06-05 13:26:39"),task = c("hop", "hop", "hop", "vj", "vj", "vj"), limb = c("L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R"), trial = c("trial1", "trial1", "trial1", "trial2", "trial2", "trial2"))
```

I want to add NA's to specific rows in the Frame and Time column (amount of NA rows to be added will vary in my real dataset). I also need to continue the task, limb, and trial column accordingly (i.e. hop, L, trial1 continues even on NA rows). My expected output to look like this:

```
> df3 
Frame             Time               task     limb    trial   
219388    2020-06-05 13:26:39        hop       L      trial1
219389    2020-06-05 13:26:39        hop       L      trial1
219390    2020-06-05 13:26:39        hop       L      trial1
NA                 NA                hop       L      trial1
NA                 NA                hop       L      trial1
NA                 NA                hop       L      trial1
211387    2020-06-05 13:26:39        vj        R      trial2
211388    2020-06-05 13:26:39        vj        R      trial2
211389    2020-06-05 13:26:39        vj        R      trial2
NA                 NA                vj        R      trial2
NA                 NA                vj        R      trial2
```

I've tried insertRows from the berryFunctions package, however this changes the whole row to NA and I need task, limb, and trial columns to continue.

```
insertRows(df3, r=c(3:5), new=NA, rcurrent=FALSE)
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `group_split` based on 'task' to 'trial' column into a `list` of data.frames, then loop over the list with `map2`, `slice` the first row, convert the 'Frame', 'Time' to `NA`, expand the dataset rows with `uncount`using the replication values passed in `map2`, bind the dataset with the original dataset (`bind_rows`) and as we are using `map2_dfr`, it returns a single data.frame by row binding the `list`

```
library(dplyr) #1.0.0
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
df3 %>%
     group_split(across(task:trial)) %>%
     map2_dfr(c(3, 2), ~ 
         slice(.x, 1) %>% 
         mutate(across(Frame:Time, ~NA)) %>% 
         uncount(.y) %>% 
         bind_rows(.x, .))
# A tibble: 11 x 5
#    Frame Time                task  limb  trial 
#    <dbl> <chr>               <chr> <chr> <chr> 
# 1 219388 2020-06-05 13:26:39 hop   L     trial1
# 2 219389 2020-06-05 13:26:39 hop   L     trial1
# 3 219390 2020-06-05 13:26:39 hop   L     trial1
# 4     NA <NA>                hop   L     trial1
# 5     NA <NA>                hop   L     trial1
# 6     NA <NA>                hop   L     trial1
# 7 211387 2020-06-05 13:26:39 vj    R     trial2
# 8 211388 2020-06-05 13:26:39 vj    R     trial2
# 9 211389 2020-06-05 13:26:39 vj    R     trial2
#10     NA <NA>                vj    R     trial2
#11     NA <NA>                vj    R     trial2
```

The `group_split` is similar to base R `split` except that it have some options to either keep the grouping variables in the `list` of data.frames or not (and it won't name the `list` elements).  The idea is to split into chunks of data.frame in a `list` where the values are the same in the grouping columns.  So, it is a way of splitting the dataset automatically without manually suggesting the row at which it needs to add more NA rows.

---

Also, if the number of `NAs` to be added are constant, another option is `group_by`, `summarise` (in the dplyr 1.0.0 - `summarise` can return more than 1 row)

```
df3  %>%
     group_by(across(task:trial)) %>%
     summarise(across(everything(), ~ c(., rep(NA, 3))))
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   task, limb, trial [2]
#   task  limb  trial   Frame Time               
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>              
# 1 hop   L     trial1 219388 2020-06-05 13:26:39
# 2 hop   L     trial1 219389 2020-06-05 13:26:39
# 3 hop   L     trial1 219390 2020-06-05 13:26:39
# 4 hop   L     trial1     NA <NA>               
# 5 hop   L     trial1     NA <NA>               
# 6 hop   L     trial1     NA <NA>               
# 7 vj    R     trial2 211387 2020-06-05 13:26:39
# 8 vj    R     trial2 211388 2020-06-05 13:26:39
# 9 vj    R     trial2 211389 2020-06-05 13:26:39
#10 vj    R     trial2     NA <NA>               
#11 vj    R     trial2     NA <NA>               
#12 vj    R     trial2     NA <NA>
```

---

Also, with `berryFunctions`, after creating `NA` rows using `insertRows`, `fill` the columns of interest

```
library(berryFunctions)
insertRows(df3, r=4:6, new=NA, rcurrent= FALSE) %>% 
       insertRows(., r = 10) %>%
       fill(task:trial)
#    Frame                Time task limb  trial
#1  219388 2020-06-05 13:26:39  hop    L trial1
#2  219389 2020-06-05 13:26:39  hop    L trial1
#3  219390 2020-06-05 13:26:39  hop    L trial1
#4      NA                <NA>  hop    L trial1
#5      NA                <NA>  hop    L trial1
#6      NA                <NA>  hop    L trial1
#7  211387 2020-06-05 13:26:39   vj    R trial2
#8  211388 2020-06-05 13:26:39   vj    R trial2
#9  211389 2020-06-05 13:26:39   vj    R trial2
#10     NA                <NA>   vj    R trial2
#11     NA                <NA>   vj    R trial2
```

Comment: Group split method worked. Could you explain the code a little further please? I'm fairly new to coding in R. This was just a sample of my data so I want to know what I need to edit in order to place NA's appropriately where I want. Thank you!

Comment: I like the berryFunctions method best, can you explain how I would do this if my data set is larger (i.e. 500 rows) and I want to set row 50-100 with NA's, row 150-200 with NA's, row 250-300 with NA's etc. Thank you!

Comment: @mpvalenc. The berryFunctions insertRows seems to be good if we want to insert NAs for a particular sequence of rows.  Otherwise, it needs to readjust the number of rows.    That was the reason I did a second insertRows statement.  Regarding the group_split, it is splitting by groups. based on the data showed, it seems to be the case for you.  I added some more explanation. Hope it helps